# CXX environment variable is not picked by Go build after first whitespace character

Tags: go, environment-variables

I am trying to change default C++ compiler that **Golang** uses to **MSVC** compiler.
I know we need to set **CXX** variable to path of MSVC compiler.

Path of MSVC compiler on my Windows machine: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe**

Commands I have used:

```
set "CXX=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe"
```

then I ran:

```
go build my_file.go
```

And now If I do `go env CXX`, output is `C:\Program`

Also, `echo %CXX%` is printing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe`

So, go build is not picking value of **CXX** after first whitespace character.

What could be the possible solution of this problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the quotes around only the *path* instead? As in `set CXX="C:\..."`?

Comment: yes @Someprogrammerdude, I have tried that, and in that case go build is taking CXX="C:\Program only.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Does this happen on the latest version of go? Can you set the correct value using [`go env -w`](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/30411-env.md) ?

Comment: @Aayushchauhan you can try quote the sub parts with space and try

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava, I tried your suggestion, but it did not work.

Comment: Oh set windows env variables so you can access the cl.exe directly from command line then set CXX="CL.exe"